# how to change some part of a softlink (in linux)

Tags: linux, symlink

I have lots of soft links in a directory. Destination of all of them starts with /home/user/. I want to change all of them to start with /home/name/. How can I do that ?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Write a shell script that iterates over all symlinks and calls `rm <oldlink> && ln -s <newlink>` to replace the link?

Comment: Please read a document titled [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Keep in mind that SO is not a free programming service, so instead of just asking for someone to do the programming for you, you'd get much more and better responses if you'd show some effort from your behalf ie. do some programming, include the code you've produced in your question and then ask some specifics about things that you can't get working.